How do I fix my audio problem when I'm video editing in blender?
So I've been working on putting a video together in blender; however, I am unable to get the audio I'm using to work properly. If I play the audio from the beginning, there is no sound, but if I scrub around, I can hear it while I'm editing. However, when I tried to render the video, the audio went dead. I imported that video into another blender file to see if that was the problem. I deleted the audio, and reused the same audio as before, but I ran into the same problem. I also tried moving the video and audio along the timeline, but I still had the same problem. I just can't play the video from the beginning, or else it won't give me any sound. I'm working on a Macbook; so I don't know if that's the problem, but if anyone knows what's going wrong, please tell me. This problem is really annoying.
These are my settings.


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

In my experience you have to work with the VSE and audio, give it a second to buffer the audio to get it to playback correctly and in sync. It's a bit finicky there. I would also wanna know what you're export settings are because most options in Blender WRT exporting video comes without audio. You can export it with audio, but it's like 2 of the dozen or so options.

Have you tried AAC as the audio codec?

I was using AAC before, and it was giving me the same problem.

I can scrub all the way to frame 2 of the audio and the audio will play, but it won't play if I go to frame 1 (the beginning).

Ok, if anyone else is having this problem, set your start one frame before the previous frame.

In my case, I needed to set the start to zero instead of one. This window is on the right hand side of the sequencer window.

Hm, sounds like a bug or some other problem to me so this might only cure the symptoms, not the cause... since I never ever had to set the audio to start one frame earlier in order to get it to work. But at least you found a solution for this case.
